# Append Django template tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-selectors, django-templates

```
<script>
    $("#tableview").css({'display' : block});
    $("#tableview").append('{{html}}');  
    or
    $("#tableview").html('{{html}}');
</script>

<div id="tableview" style="display:none;"></div>
```

the {{html}} i.e, generated on the server gets displayed which is,`<div id=""newdiv">contetssdddddddd</div>`.This is displayed on the UI

how to embed the html in the body

Comment: You didn't the question.

Comment: Is this a JavaScript question or a Django question? Template tag should work ok if this JavaScript is in template that is rendered by Django. And `append()` should work in jQuery AFAIK. What is the exact problem you are having? Be more specific please.

Comment: The question is related to both ,template tag works and gives the output as excepted.but jquery consider this as string and displays this generated html on the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `{{ html|escapejs }}` with `append()`

[read this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs)